# Solutions of Differential Equations and Integral Equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Are integral equations and differential equations allways equivalent, i.e. the set of solutions is equal? The following are my thoughts about it. Are they correct?

---

Let's define the function $x:\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R$ by the integral equation
$$x(t)=g(t)+\int_0^t f(x(s))\mathrm{d}s,\qquad x(0)=g(0)=a,$$
whereas $g\in\mathcal C^1(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$, $f\in\mathcal C(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$ and $a\in\Bbb R$.

We are looking for all solutions of $x$ in the space $\mathcal C(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$. Let's call this the integral equation problem (IEP).

Although not required in the conditions, from the equation already follows, that $x$ is in $\mathcal C^1(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$, since the right hand side is in $\mathcal C^1(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus and $g\in\mathcal C^1(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$, $f,x\in\mathcal C(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$. As $x$ is differentiable, we can differentiate the equation and get
$$x'(t)=g'(t)+f(x(t)),\qquad x(0)=g(0)=a,$$
again with $g\in\mathcal C^1(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$, $f\in\mathcal C(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$ and $a\in\Bbb R$. The search for all solutions of $x$ in the space $\mathcal C^1(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$ we call the differential equation problem (DEP).

Simply by integrating we can transform the DEP back to the IEP. This shows that the IEP and the DEP are equivalent.

---

Are $g\in\mathcal{C}^1(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$, $f,x\in\mathcal C(\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R)$ and $a\in\Bbb R$ the weakest assumptions we have to assume? I think so.

The reason why I think that the equivalence of the problems is helpful, is that for the DEP we have theorems like from Picard–Lindelöf, which can be used for the IEP then.

Comment: The Picard-Lindelof is just a flavor of the Banach fixed point theorem, applied in a particular context. In fact, the proof of the Picard theorem starts by converting the problem to an integral equation!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/253951/721644).

Comment: Ypu can simply use `\Bbb R` for $\Bbb R$ and `\mathcal C` For $\mathcal C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumptions in the OP the two problems IEP and DEP are equivalent.

The continuity of $f$ guarantees the existence of a local solution, i.e., a solution defined in an interval $[0,T)$, which is not necessarily unique.

In order to obtain uniqueness, we need additional conditions on $f$. For example, local Lipschitz continuity or positivity.

In order to obtain a global existence, i.e., solution defined in $[0,\infty)$, we need further conditions on the growth rate of $f$. For example:
$$
|f(x)|\le F(x) \quad\&\quad \int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{F(x)}=\infty.
$$